# Redirecting Standard Output And Standard Error to One File

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I have come to understand that we have two methods of redirecting both stdout and stderr to the same file. The first method is:
`ls -l /bin > ls-output.txt 2>&1`
As the author of [this book](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/) states: Using this method, we perform 2 redirections, first we redirect stdout to ls-output.txt and then we redirect stderr(file descriptor 2) to stdout(using file descriptor 1).

**The order of redirections is important.**

`ls -l /bin 2>&1 >ls-output.txt` would redirect stderr to screen.

My question is: Like in many programming languages, was the command designed with some associativity and precedence rules in mind *and* how do we read the command while writing it on screen? *and* what is the sequence of the backend execution of the command?

Here's what i think about the execution sequence:
First, the command `ls -l /bin` sends its output to stdout and error to stderr(any one of those).
Then, the stderr is redirected to stdout.(if there is any error, eg: if `ls -l /binn` is used)
Now, the stdout stream contains one of the two(either output or error) which it then redirects to the file *ls-output.txt*

Comment: The redirection happens before `ls` ever starts. It's handled by the shell. See, for example, the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial), or the links in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604141/cheat-sheet-exhibiting-bash-shell-stdout-stderr-redirection-behavior).

Comment: Your question asks about standard output and standard error. Why does the title refer to standard **input**?

Comment: @Barmar, sorry it was a typo, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirections are processed from left to right. When you execute:

```
ls -l /bin >ls-output.txt 2>&1
```

the shell performs approximately the following operations internally:

```
fork(); // Then in the child process:
fd = open("ls-output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
dup2(fd, 1);
close(fd);
// 2>&1
dup2(1, 2);
```

Then it executes the `ls -l /bin` command with these descriptor attachments in place. Since you redirect `stdout` to the file first, the redirection of `stderr` inherits that redirection.

If you were to write

```
ls -l /bin 2>&1 >ls-output.txt
```

The order of operations would be inverted:

```
// 2>&1
dup2(1, 2);
// >ls-output.txt
fd = open("ls-output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
dup2(fd, 1);
close(fd);
```

This connects `stderr` to the original `stdout`, which is likely to be the terminal. Then it redirects `stdout` to a file; this has no effect on `stderr`.

Comment: Some extra info: [dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) _`dup2()` makes `newfd` be the copy of `oldfd`, closing `newfd` first if necessary..._ .